# Free score writer?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, music-production

I am looking for a free score writer for my Windows 7 PC.

I only have a total of 2 GB ram available in my desktop.

Comment: Additionally, it lacks a lot of the details required for a question here, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)